# How to check a checkbox which is not visible?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, selenium-webdriver-c#

I need to check a checkbox, but am not able to do that. It's giving the error:
`Element is not visible`

This is the element:

```
<input _ngcontent-c5="" class="lb-checkbox ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" id="1" ng-reflect-model="false">
::after </input>
```

And this is the code I tried:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("1")).Click()
```

Comment: What hv you tried? Edit and add your code.

Comment: First of all you shouldn't try to manipulate  an element that isn't visible since it doesn't represent user behaviour. If you really want to do it try ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", yourWebElement); but like I said, I'd recommend to go for a whatever triggers the hidden element instead.

Comment: Exactly what @godisalie92 says: why do you think that performing action which user cannot do will make a valid e2e test? What you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

First verify the checkbox is already selected or not by using the if condition. Use this below code

```
boolean iconEnabled = driver.findElement(By.id("1")).isEnabled();

if(iconEnabled == true)
{

    WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.id("1"));
    checkbox.click();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JavascriptExecutor` to change the display attribute to make the element visible then perform the click.

```
JavascriptExecutor executor4= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;        
executor4.executeScript("document.getElementById('1').style.display='block';"); 
driver.FindElement(By.Id("1")).Click();
```

Above code make the checkbox visible so you can click on it.